# Shopware clears cart and redirects to registration page on session timeout

Tags: shopware

Customers have their cart cleared after their session times out, but are not warned about this, and are confusingly redirected to the registration page. Is this standard Shopware behaviour? Or have I broken something?

**Setup**: Using Shopware 5.4.6 via composer.

**Recreating the problem**: A customers visits the site (and maybe add items to their cart), then re-visits after their session has timed out, adds more items to their cart and continues to checkout.

**Expected behaviour**: I would expect to see a warning that the session has timed out and maybe return them to the homepage or an empty cart.

**Actual behaviour**: What actually happens is that they can still add items to their cart, but when they try to checkout their cart is emptied and they are redirected to the registration page.

This looks to be caused by a new session being started, and is very confusing for customers as the registration page looks a lot like the start of the checkout so they fill in some name and address details... but then they do not progress to the checkout as their cart is inexplicably empty.

The question is whether the behaviour *after* sessions time out is normal, and if so if there's any way to make it less awful for visitors?

**Note on sessions**: Sessions time out - this is normal, and the timing of this is controlled via php.ini. That's not the issue here - you could set the time out to a day or a week and this issue would still occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently this is the default behaviour of shopware. You need to add your own logic via plugin. The login and cart is lost after the session timed out.

Comment: Thank-you. I'll look into writing a plugin or possibly a pull request so that everyone can get a better default behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the standard shopware this functionality is not provided. You can either try to implement yourself the functionality or use plugins from the store ([Search session](https://store.shopware.com/search?sSearch=session) or [Countdown Session](https://store.shopware.com/overh51947046264f/warenkorb-countdown-session-timeout-verlaengerung.html))

Comment: Plugins don't really fix this issue, but thank-you for the suggestion.

Comment: I think the countdown session is exactly what you want `Expected behaviour: I would expect to see a warning that the session has timed out and maybe return them to the homepage or an empty cart.`, but maybe there is more to the picture that is not shared here.

Comment: Maybe the countdown timer does something different than described - the English description is rather hard to understand, and appears to be crippled if you don't sign up for some external service :)